# Compound Interest Daily Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

How would I take a fixed rate such as 1.5% use daily compound interest in order to exponentially grow another number?

For example, I have an interest rate of 1.5 every day I want 1.5% of 1,000 to be added to the 1,000. So that tomorrow it will be 1015 and the process will continue.

Answer (score -1):

(Start Date)A1 = dd/mm/yyyy
(Formula For Todays date) A2 =Today()
(Starting Amount)A3 = 1000
(Compounded Amount)A4 =(A2-A1)*-0.015*1000+1000